# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - Keras Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer?version=stable#example_4) on the TensorFlow site, but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def vectorize(vector_like):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(vector_like)

def batchify(vector):
    '''Make a batch out of a single example'''
    return vectorize([vector])

data = [(batchify([0]), batchify([0, 0, 0])), (batchify([1]), batchify([0, 0, 0])), (batchify([2]), batchify([0, 0, 0]))]
num_hidden = 5
num_classes = 3

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
loss_fn = lambda: tf.keras.backend.cast(tf.keras.losses.mse(model(input), output), tf.float32)
var_list_fn = lambda: model.trainable_weights
for input, output in data:
    opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list_fn)
```

For a while, I was getting a warning about the loss function having the wrong datatype (int instead of float), which is why I've added the casting to the loss function.

Instead of the network training, I'm instead getting the error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:
>   ['sequential/dense/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense/bias:0',
>   'sequential/dense_1/kernel:0', 'sequential/dense_1/bias:0'].

**Why aren't the gradients getting passed through?** What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GradientTape` if you want to manipulate gradients in TF2. For example, following works.

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  loss = tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.losses.mse(model(input),tf.cast(output, tf.float32)))

gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

**Edit**:

You can actually get your sample to work by doing the following changes.

- Using cast just for the output instead of the full `loss_fn` (note I'm also doing a `mean` as we optimize w.r.t mean of loss)

By "work", I mean it doesn't complain. But you will need to further investigate to make sure it's working as intended.

```
loss_fn = lambda: tf.keras.backend.mean(tf.keras.losses.mse(model(input), tf.cast(output, tf.float32)))
var_list_fn = lambda: model.trainable_weights

opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list_fn)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Why doesn't [the example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer?version=stable#example_4) use `GradientTape` if it is necessary?

Comment: It could very well be a bug. But unfortunately I don't know the exact answer for that.

Comment: @ProQ Think I found something useful. edited my answer.

Comment: It looks like in order to make predictions I also need the data to be a float32. So changing the `vectorize` function to `tf.convert_to_tensor(vector_like, dtype=tf.float32)` fixed everything. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Okay, I guess this won't help with [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249708/valueerror-no-gradients-provided-for-any-variable-tensorflow-2-0-keras)? Any idea what could cause this error when using `model.fit()`?